# Disable column in MSHFlexGrid in VB6.0

Tags: vb6, activex

How do I disable particular columns in `MSHFlexgrid` in VB6.0?  I don't want my user to edit the values in a particular column.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the MSHFlexGrid control allows users to edit its data in the first place. Therefore, in effect, all columns are disabled. Job done :)

In fact, you have to add custom code to enable updating e.g. add an appropriate control (textbox, combo, date picker, etc) that *does* allow editing, hide it at design time, then at run time detect which grid cell should have focus, move and size the control to fit the cell then make it visible then handle events to validate the input then write the contents back to the recordset...

...or you could purchase a third party control that does all this out of the box. The MSHFlexGrid that ships with VB6 is essentially a cut-down version of [VSFlexGrid Pro](http://www.componentsource.com/products/componentone-vsflexgrid-pro/index.html), which I've used and thought was quite good. It has a different way of handling hierarchical data by creating groups (rather than bands) which is superior, IMO. The best thing that can be said about the MSHFlexGrid is that it is easy to bind to a hierarchical ADO recordset to simply display the results but not good if you want to do nice formatting or make the grid editable. The VSFlexGrid Pro, if you can afford it, has more power e.g. you can create data source classes to handle binding to custom data structures (ships with VB6 examples of this including ADO recordset binding) which would be invaluable IMO if you intend to make your hierarchical grid editable.

Answer (score 0):

'A Shortcut way is here...  NOT in a proper way.  But you can try

'if you need to lock the first 3 columns please use this code:

```
msf2=name of MSFlexGrid
Private Sub msF2_EnterCell()
With msF2
    If msF2.Col = 0 Or msF2.Col = 1 Or msF2.Col = 2 Then
        msF2.Col = 3
    End If
End With
End Sub
```